How to derive the general term of this sequence?
Here's the information we have about the sequence:
a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2

And when n>=2
a[n + 1] - n == a[n] - 1

Based on the known conditions above, determine the general term of the sequence.
Using the following code, we cannot derive the general term of the sequence.
RSolve[{a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2, a[n + 1] - n == a[n] - 1, n >= 2}, a[n],
  n]

And
RSolve[{a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2, a[n + 1] - n == a[n] - 1}, a[n], n]

The initial conditions for this sequence problem are not wrong. The adaptability condition given by the recursive formula is that when n is equal to or equal to 2, a1= = 1 exists independently of the recursive formula. Therefore, the question I asked was how to make the software automatically generate the answer shown in the following figure:


You have too many initial conditions. What happens if you remove the a[1]==1?

The general term formula obtained is in a segmented form; how come this software can't automatically provide the segmented form?

If you specify too many initial conditions, they must be correct relative to the recurrence relation. However, your initial conditions are wrong. For n==1 the recurrence relation reads: a[1 + 1] - 1 == a[1] - 1 Therefore:  2 - 1 == 1 - 1 what is wrong.

(-1) Still, you're coding blindly, if a[n + 1] - n == a[n] - 1 is valid only for n>=2, how can it be translated as something like  {a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2, a[n + 1] - n == a[n] - 1, n >= 2} or {a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2, a[n + 1] - n == a[n] - 1}? Also, please put a bit more effort in formating your question properly.

Just for completeness, here's a way of setting up this solution directly as a holonomic sequence: using only the second boundary condition,
A = DifferenceRoot[Function[{a, n}, {a[n+1] - n == a[n] - 1, a[2] == 2}]];

In this case, Mathematica knows how to simplify it into an explicit form:
A[n] // FullSimplify
(*    3 + 1/2 (-3 + n) n    *)

However, DifferenceRoot is much more powerful than that, and can be manipulated symbolically just like the more well-known Root.
As DifferenceRoot is very general, we can try to set it up with the two boundary conditions given by the OP:
B = DifferenceRoot[Function[{a, n}, {a[n+1] - n == a[n] - 1, a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2}]];

Now we don't get an explicit answer:
B[n] // FullSimplify
(*    DifferenceRoot[...][n]    *)

But we can nonetheless evaluate it for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$:
Table[B[n], {n, -10, 10}]
(*    {67, 56, 46, 37, 29, 22, 16, 11, 7, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 17, 23, 30, 38}    *)

There is only one place where the generic equality is overruled by the given specific values:
Table[B[n + 1] - n == B[n] - 1, {n, -10, 10}]
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}    *)


If you specify too many initial conditions, they must be correct relative to the recurrence relation. However, your initial conditions are wrong. For n==1 the recurrence relation reads: a[1 + 1] - 1 == a[1] - 1 Therefore:  2 - 1 == 1 - 1 what is wrong.
With the correct number of initial conditions, either a[1]==1 or a[2]==2:
RSolve[{a[1] == 1, a[n + 1] == a[n] + n - 1}, a[n], n]

{{a[n] -> 1/2 (4 - 3 n + n^2)}}

Or with a[2]==2:
RSolve[{a[2] == 2, a[n + 1] == a[n] + n - 1}, a[n], n]

{{a[n] -> 1/2 (6 - 3 n + n^2)}}


The initial conditions for this sequence problem are not wrong. The adaptability condition given by the recursive formula is that when n is equal to or equal to 2, a1= = 1 exists independently of the recursive formula.

You can not bend the rules to your liking. However, simply start your sequence with n==2.

As has been already expressed, the desired result can be obtained for $n\geq 2$ by using the relevant initial condition $a(2)=2$
For example:
RSolveValue[{DifferenceDelta[a[n],n]==n-1,a[2]==2},a,n][n]


